# Getting network related error while doing any action on Oracle cloud console

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

While doing any action like trying to click on VNC menu or create instance menu from navigation I get the following error.

> Something went wrong with the last request, but you might be able to
>   fix the problem.Ask your network administrator to allow network
>   traffic over HTTPS. Usually this involves updating network proxy
>   settings. If that doesn't work, please contact support.

[image]

Comment: Can you still reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes, Mine is a free tier account. Till this day I was not able to create instance whenever I go on that page it gives me the above error. From home network and office network.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid this might be an issue of your network configuration. Could you please test it from a different network and from a different computer?

Comment: Today I experience the same issue, so working on it, will update you once I have any solution.

Comment: There was an issue with the OCI Console, which was mitigated recently, so for me it works again. Could you please check if it helped you, as well? You can see the incident report here: https://ocistatus.oraclecloud.com/incidents/98rk18wwv58m

Comment: Yes, it started working but unfortunately, it was too late. I had mostly exhausted the free tier days. So I could never really use ICS.

Comment: I recently created an account with oracle cloud and am getting the same error on trying to start an instance. Is anyone else facing a similar issue?